# Listing fetched records in an Ember template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to learn ember by following along with [Vic Ramons Ember Rails tutorial](http://ember.vicramon.com/chapters/all).

I'm stuck trying to list the users I have fetched from Rails.

```
<!-- /templates/users.handlebars -->
<article id="users">
  <h2>Users</h2>
  <ul>
      {{#each user in controller }}
          <li>{{ user.email }}</li>
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
</article>
```

The `/templates/users.handlebars` is rendered but no users are listed.

I have checked the JSON output which is ok. When I check the ember inspector tab in chrome I can see 20 'user' models in the Data section.

**What is the correct way to list the user records?**

[image: screenshot]

/routes/users.js:

```
Tagged.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){ return this.store.findAll('user') }
});
```

/models/users.js:

```
Tagged.User = DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string')
});
```

/controllers/users.js:

```
Tagged.UsersController = Ember.Controller.extend({

});
```

/router.js:

```
Tagged.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('users', { path: '/users' })
});
```

adapters/application_adapter.js:

```
Tagged.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({});
```

The controller JSON response:

```
{ "users":[
    {"id":"5599bbc44d6178d3ae000000","email":"sasha@example.com"},
    {"id":"5599bbc54d6178d3ae000001","email":"roberta@example.com"},
    {"id":"5599bbc54d6178d3ae000002","email":"reyna.mayert@example.com"}
    # ...
] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<article id="users">
  <h2>Users</h2>
  <ul>
      {{#each user in model }}
          <li>{{ user.email }}</li>
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: you can add some explanation?

Comment: Not really needed, it was a simple oneliner error in the tutorial I was following.

Comment: #each requires the value after in to be iterable. the controller being a normal controller is not iterable but its model property is iterable.

Answer (score 0):

In templates model property of controller is not usually used. If you change you /controllers/users.js to:

```
Tagged.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});
```

It should work. Because UsersController becomes a ArrayController which works with #each while normal controller does not.

Comment: But ArrayController seems to be depreciated. https://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/7f6016e426005146f593